# No callback while using UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift4, uidocumentpickervc

I'm using UIDocumentPickerViewController to select a document from the iPhone.

I have implemented the feature in the following way.

```
class Si3EntityDocumentViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate, UIDocumentPickerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIDocumentMenuDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setLoader()
        getDocuments(id:entity.id)
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.setTitle("Upload Doc", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!){
        let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypeText),String(kUTTypeContent),String(kUTTypeItem),String(kUTTypeData)], in: .import)
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: {
            documentPicker.delegate = self
        } )
    }

    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        print(urls)
    }

}
```

The `func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt url: URL)` method has been deprecated in iOS 11 so i have replaced it with `func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL])`

For some reason, I'm not getting the callback in `func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL])`

I also have some other code in this class but I've not included it.
When I select a document or click cancel I get the following error in the console

> [DocumentManager] The view service did terminate with error: Error
>   Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={Terminated=disconnect method}

I know I'm missing out something very silly, any help is appreciated.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller) for a better understanding.

The default behaviour of a UIDocumentPickerViewController is to pick one document and you would have to use:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
}
```

If you are using the UIDocumentPickerViewController to pick multiple documents, then you will have to set the **`allowsMultipleSelection`** property to `true` and implement

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
}
```

Also, the following line would suffice.

```
present(documentPicker, animated: true)
```

Comment: `func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
}` has been deprecated for iOS 11. So using `documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
}` makes no sense. Also I tried setting **allowsMultipleSelection** doesn't help.

Comment: Then please refer the documentation. I gave you code snippets that I have used and are working, tested on a device before posting.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerdelegate/2902364-documentpicker

Comment: Also, if a solution works for you (as more than one are posted), kindly select it as the accepted answer, it helps other users.

Answer (score 0):

I Used this Methods in swift 3

```
func openImportDocumentPicker() {
    let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.item"], in: .import)
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
}

func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
    if controller.documentPickerMode == .import {
        let alertMessage: String = "Successfully imported \(url.absoluteURL)"
   }
}

func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
    print("Cancelled")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try on a device. Simulator wasn't working for me when I logged into iCloud and tried to view a directory.